# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I try to flush, I am getting below exception,

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.dao.Employee; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.dao.Employee

Pls let me know what is the wrong while flusing.

Code:

```
..........
..........
while (i.hasNext()) {
  EmpAddressList p = (EmpAddressList ) i.next();
  this.getHibernateTemplate().save(p);
  this.getHibernateTemplate().flush();
}
......
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Error say itself where's the error. You need to save `com.dao.Employee` object first before flushing.

Comment: But I saved the Employee object before its child flusing.

Comment: Code: this.getHibernateTemplate().persist(employee);
this.getSession().flush();

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check if you are attaching the employee to the EmpAddressList after you have saved the employee and not before.

```
getHibernateTemplate().persist(employee); 
this.getSession().flush();
empAddressList.setEmployee(employee);
```